# Hitting tab on keyboard is copying blank text into my clipboard

Tags: sublimetext3

Whenever I hit tab in sublime editor it copies blank or nearby content into my clipboard, overwriting what's in my clipboard and what I intend to paste.

I'm trying to find out how or where to stop this.

Does anyone know how to find or change any actions happening when I hit tab?

Answer (score 1):

I deleted packages one by one to debug.

The package **Emmet Style Reflector** was causing this. Removed and now tab is not copying empty spaces.